# Identify Auto generating Rows in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have created a application which create rows dynamically ( automatically ) when the user enter done ( in numeric keypad) . the first row is defined static manner and from the code behind rows will be created automatically followed by the columns according to the predefined columns in the first row .Xaml code as below.

```
<StackLayout>
                <Label Text="SALES ORDER" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" BackgroundColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
            <Grid x:Name="thegrid" RowSpacing="7" ColumnSpacing="1" BackgroundColor="White">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Label  x:Name="B1" Text = "ROUTE CODE" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  FontSize="15" BackgroundColor="Gray" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White"/>
                <Label  x:Name="B2" Text = "" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  FontSize="15" BackgroundColor="White"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black"/>
                <Label x:Name="B3" Text = "SHOP CODE" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"  FontSize="15" BackgroundColor="Gray"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White"/>
                <Label x:Name="B4" Text = "Admin" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"  FontSize="15" BackgroundColor="White"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black"/>

                <Label  x:Name="B5" Text = "INVOICE DATE" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"  FontSize="15" BackgroundColor="Gray" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White"/>
                <DatePicker x:Name="radDateTimePicker1" MinimumDate="01/01/1990" MaximumDate="01/01/2030" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                <Label  x:Name="B10" Text="{Binding Date, Source={x:Reference radDateTimePicker1},StringFormat='{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}'}" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1"  FontSize="15" BackgroundColor="White"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" />


               <!-- <Label  x:Name="B15" Text = "AREA" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0"  FontSize="Medium" BackgroundColor="Gray" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White"/>
                <Label  x:Name="B25" Text = "UVA" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"  FontSize="Medium" BackgroundColor="White"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black"/>-->

                <Label  x:Name="B35" Text = "SHOP NAME" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0"  FontSize="15" BackgroundColor="Gray" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White"/>
                <Label  x:Name="B45" Text = "RADHA TRADERS" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1"  FontSize="15" BackgroundColor="White"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black"/>

                <Label  x:Name="B55" Text = "SALES ORDER" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"  FontSize="15" BackgroundColor="Gray" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White"/>
                <Label  x:Name="B65" Text = "HATTON" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"  FontSize="15" BackgroundColor="White"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black"/>




                <Label x:Name="B7" Text = "AGENCY NAME" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"  FontSize="15" BackgroundColor="Gray"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White"/>
                <Picker x:Name="PickerListtwo" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" BackgroundColor="White" IsVisible="False" SelectedIndexChanged="PickerList_SelectedIndexChangedtwo">
                    <Picker.Items>
                        <x:String>Mohammed R</x:String>
                        <x:String>Sanath J</x:String>
                        <x:String>Rahul R</x:String>
                        <x:String>Mohammed I</x:String>
                        <x:String>Thuwan A</x:String>
                        <x:String>Praveen K</x:String>
                        <x:String>Roshan P</x:String>
                    </Picker.Items>
                </Picker>
                <Label x:Name="PickerLabeltwo" Text="CUSTOMER" FontSize="15" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center">
                    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tappedtwo"/>
                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                </Label>

                <!--<Label  x:Name="B9" Text = "" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"  FontSize="Medium" BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White"/>-->

                <Label x:Name="B11" Text = "AGENCY CODE" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2"  FontSize="15" BackgroundColor="Gray"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" />
                <Label x:Name="outstanding" Text = "" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3"  FontSize="15" BackgroundColor="White"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Red"/>
                <Label x:Name="CRTOP" Text = "AREA" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2"  FontSize="15" BackgroundColor="Gray"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White"/>
                <Label x:Name="CRANS" Text = "" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3"  FontSize="15" BackgroundColor="White"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Red"/>
                <Label x:Name="CRBAL" Text = "OPEARTION" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2"  FontSize="15" BackgroundColor="Gray"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White"/>
                <Label x:Name="BALANS" Text = "" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="3"  FontSize="15" BackgroundColor="White"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Red"/>
                <Label x:Name="ADDRESSN" Text = "ADDRESS" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="2"  FontSize="15" BackgroundColor="Gray"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White"/>
                <Label x:Name="ADDRESSV" Text = "" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="3"  FontSize="15" BackgroundColor="White"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Red"/>
            </Grid>

            <Grid x:Name="controlGrid" RowSpacing="2" ColumnSpacing="1.5" BackgroundColor="Black" >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                    <!--<RowDefinition Height="50" />-->
                    <!--<RowDefinition Height="50" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />

                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />-->


                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />

                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label  x:Name="Btn_1" Text = "PRODUCT" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  FontSize="15" BackgroundColor="Gray" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White"/>
                <Label  x:Name="Btn_2" Text = "QTY" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"  FontSize="15" BackgroundColor="Gray"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White"/>
                <Label x:Name="Btn_3" Text = "PRICE" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  FontSize="15" BackgroundColor="Gray"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White"/>
                <Label x:Name="Btn_4" Text = "FREE ISSUE" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"  FontSize="15" BackgroundColor="Gray"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White"/>
                <Label x:Name="Btn_5" Text = "UNIT TOTAL" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4"  FontSize="15" BackgroundColor="Gray"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White"/>


                <Label x:Name="PickerLabelthree" Text="1 SELECT PRODUCT" FontSize="12" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="White" TextColor="Black" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
                    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tappedthree"/>
                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                </Label>

                <Entry  x:Name="Qtyone" TextChanged="SetRepairPercent" Keyboard="Numeric" Completed="Qtyone_Completed" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" BackgroundColor="White" FontSize="15" TextColor="Black"  />

                <Entry  x:Name="Priceoneout" TextChanged="SetRepairPercent" Keyboard="Numeric"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="White" FontSize="15" TextColor="Black"  />

                <Label  x:Name="Totone" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3"  BackgroundColor="White" FontSize="15" TextColor="Black" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />

                <Entry  x:Name="TotoneR" TextChanged="SetRepairPercent" Keyboard="Numeric"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4"  BackgroundColor="White" FontSize="15" TextColor="Black"  />
```

and the auto generation row code behind as below

```
private void Qtyone_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddARowToGridView();
           // TotoneR.Text = "13.5";
        }

        int rowCount;
        private void AddARowToGridView()
        {


            Label PickerLabelthree = new Label();
            PickerLabelthree.Text = "1 SELECT PRODUCT";
            PickerLabelthree.FontSize = 15;
            PickerLabelthree.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
            PickerLabelthree.TextColor = Color.Black;
            PickerLabelthree.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
            PickerLabelthree.HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
            PickerLabelthree.VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
            // PickerLabelthree.Text = pickelabelthr;
            // PickerLabelthree.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer((view) => OnLabelClicked()));
          //  SalesPopup.testing = PickerLabelthree.Text;

            PickerLabelthree.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
            {
                Command = new Command(() => OnLabelClicked()),
            });





            //PickerLabelthree.GestureRecognizers.Add() += TapGestureRecognizer_Tappedthree;


            Entry Qtyone = new Entry();
            Qtyone.Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric;
            Qtyone.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
            Qtyone.FontSize = 12;
            Qtyone.TextColor = Color.Black;
            Qtyone.TextChanged += SetRepairPercent;
            Qtyone.Completed += Qtyone_Completed;





            Entry Priceoneout = new Entry();
            Priceoneout.TextChanged += SetRepairPercent;
            Priceoneout.Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric;
            Priceoneout.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
            Priceoneout.FontSize = 12;
            Priceoneout.TextColor = Color.Black;

            Label Totone = new Label();
            Totone.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
            Totone.FontSize = 12;
            Totone.TextColor = Color.Black;
            Totone.HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
            Totone.VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;

            Entry TotoneR = new Entry();
            TotoneR.Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric;
            TotoneR.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
            TotoneR.TextColor = Color.Black;
            TotoneR.FontSize = 12;
            TotoneR.TextChanged += SetRepairPercent;


            //double _qtyoneamount;
            //_qtyoneamount = this.Qtyoneans * this.Priceoneans;
            //TotoneR.Text = _qtyoneamount.ToString();




            controlGrid.Children.Add(PickerLabelthree, 0, Convert.ToInt32(rowCount));
            controlGrid.Children.Add(Priceoneout, 1, Convert.ToInt32(rowCount));
            controlGrid.Children.Add(Qtyone, 2, Convert.ToInt32(rowCount));
            controlGrid.Children.Add(Totone, 3, Convert.ToInt32(rowCount));
            controlGrid.Children.Add(TotoneR, 4, Convert.ToInt32(rowCount));

           // TotoneR.Text = "13.5";
            rowCount++;


        }
```

so the question is , i am unable to identify the details of the cells in rows creating automatically (to get the reference of the column cells)  in the newly generating rows.( because the reason want to identify the new column row cells is that we need to calculate the price and quantity to calculate the total value in the last column) . Help will be highly appreciated and thank you in-advance for your support .

Comment: would recommend using ObservableCollection to keep track of all row objects and use the CollectionChanged event to do whatever else you need to do any time one is added/changed or for doing operations across all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's best to use an `ObservableCollection` instead, the reason your solution is not working is because you are not adding the children to the Grid in the Main/UI Thread. The `Qtyone_Completed` event handler creates another thread for the execution of the layout change. You can make it work by enclosing those lines in a function like this

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
    controlGrid.Children.Add(PickerLabelthree, 0, Convert.ToInt32(rowCount));
    controlGrid.Children.Add(Priceoneout, 1, Convert.ToInt32(rowCount));
    controlGrid.Children.Add(Qtyone, 2, Convert.ToInt32(rowCount));
    controlGrid.Children.Add(Totone, 3, Convert.ToInt32(rowCount));
    controlGrid.Children.Add(TotoneR, 4, Convert.ToInt32(rowCount));
});
```